# How can I take multiple words as one argument in Discord.Js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to make a command like `!ban <mentioned_user> <reason>`.
But I tried many ways to do but nothing suits for my code, I want to get the reason string as `args[1]`.

I used this code to fetch all arguments and to store all argument in ***args*** variable...

```
let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
let command = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();
let args = messageArray.slice(1);
```

Comment: You can `join` them back by a space: `const reason = args.join(' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that

```
const argument = msg.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
const comand = argument.shift().toLowerCase();
if(comand === `${prefix}ban`) {
        const user = argument[0];
        const reason = argument.slice(1).join(' ');
        // ban user
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, `message.content` contains `"<mentioned_user> <reason>"`

If I'm correct, you can get each in a variable and then do what you want with it

```
const [mentionedUser, ...arrRreason] = message.content.split(" ");
const reason = arrReason.join(' ');

// or

const reason = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Comment: but I want reason as like this --> ```"banned for spamming"```

Comment: if the reason contains spaces too, you can use the rest operator. I have edited my answer to illustrate.

Comment: I added a substring version